# If $\|x\| = \|y\| = 1$ and $H(\lambda x + z) = \lambda y\mathop \Rightarrow \limits^? Hx = y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $x, y \in \mathbf{C}^n$ and $\|x\| = \|y\| = 1$. Define a linear map $H \colon \mathbf{C}^n \to \mathbf{C}^n$ by
$$
H(\lambda x + z) = \lambda y
$$
for each $\lambda \in \mathbf{C}$ and each $z \in \{x\}^\perp$.
Is this true that  $Hx = y$.?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: @ Hetebrij - Why?

Comment: Hint: Since $H(\lambda x + z) = \lambda y$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbf{C}$ and all $z\in\{x\}^\perp$ consider what happens when $\lambda = 0$.